# How can i create multidimensional list in Python?

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

How can i create a multidimensional list while iterating through a 1d list based upon some condition.

I am iterating over a 1d list and whenever i find a '\n' i should append the so created list with a new list, for example,

```
 a = [1,2,3,4,5,'\n',6,7,8,9,0,'\n',3,45,6,7,2]
```

so I want it to be as,

```
new_list = [[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9,0],[3,45,6,7,2]]
```

how should i do it? Please help

```
def storeData(k):
    global dataList
    dlist = []
    for y in k:
        if y != '\n':
            dlist.append(y)
        else:
            break
    return dlist
```

This is what i have tried.

Comment: Given the input is an empty list. What is the expected result?

Comment: You should probably change whatever code produced this bizarre input list. Post-processing it is the wrong way to go.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I would assume an empty list, but better if the OP says.

Comment: i just simply want to convert the 'a' list into the 'new_list' format

Comment: Your code has a parameter `k` and a global `datalist`. Not sure what the global is for - delete it. You want a list of lists but are only using 1 list `dlist`. Seems like you you need to build a sublist, then add the sublist to dlist whenever you see a '\n'.

Comment: his will work only for this kind of data, it's a hack:

new_data = ','.join(map(str,data)).split(',\n,')
for d in new_data:
 d = d.split(',')
you could also oneline this with more uses on "map"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby` would do the job (grouping by *not* being a linefeed):

```
import itertools

a = [1,2,3,4,5,'\n',6,7,8,9,0,'\n',3,45,6,7,2]

new_list = [list(x) for k,x in itertools.groupby(a,key=lambda x : x!='\n') if k]

print(new_list)
```

We compare the key truth value to filter out the occurrences of `\n`

result:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 0], [3, 45, 6, 7, 2]]
```

Comment: You could use the currently-ignored key values from groupby to eliminate the second pass.

Comment: @user2357112 fixed. It's much better, you're right!

Answer (score 3):

example code:

```
lst = [[]]
for x in a:
    if x != '\n':
        lst[-1].append(x)
    else:
        lst.append([])
print(lst)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 0], [3, 45, 6, 7, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic approach:

**EDIT**: Good heavens! Silly bug... here's a fix:

```
>>> sub = []
>>> final = []
>>> for e in a:
...     if e == '\n':
...         final.append(sub)
...         sub = []
...     else:
...         sub.append(e)
... else:
...     final.append(sub)
...
>>> final
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 0], [3, 45, 6, 7, 2]]
>>>
```

There are other ways, but this is the naive imperative way.

Comment: OPs question and desired result don't quite line up. They want  [[1,2,3,4],[6,7,8,9,0],[3,45,6,7,2]]  not [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9, 0]]. You need a condition to add sub to the end of final if you run out of items in a without seeing another '\n'.

Comment: @Fruitspunchsamurai yes, yes. My mistake.

Comment: Why do `final.append(sub)` in an `else`? And the `...` btw make this really cumbersome to test...

Comment: @StefanPochmann My use of `else` is a personal preference. To my mind, it helps my eyes look at the code as a "logical unit", so that I know that whatever I'm doing in the `else` is somehow cleaning up whatever is going on in my for-loop. It is obviously not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it but there must be better solutions.

```
x = 0
output = [[]]
for item in a:
    if item != "\n":
        output[x].append(item)
    else:
        x += 1
        output.append([])

print(output)
```